# How to map standard deviation value to a closed interval range?

Tags: statistics

Q. Given the schedule of occurrences of some events in the last $28$ days, calculate the consistency score out of $1-10$, $10$ being most consistent.

For example, assuming an interval of $28$ days, if $3$ events occur on `day-7`, `day-15` and `day-21`, then the score should be $10$ as the events are evenly distributed.

*My approach*

I am taking the difference in days between events and calculating the standard deviation to find the spread. Problem is that `I have to map the SD to range 1-10`. For that, I need to calculate the worst possible distribution of events, given the number of days and number of events.
So for the above example, I have to find a set of $3$ days in the interval of $28$ days, for which the SD is maximized. I guess I have to identify a set of three numbers such as their sum is less than $27$ and spread is maximum. I am stuck here.

How should I proceed from here, given that the dataset is going to be large, and I can not afford an exhaustive search technique? Is there any approach to achieve this which is cheaper?